# How Can I install tailwind on an existing webpack npm project

Tags: npm, webpack, tailwind-css

I want to use tailwind css to reduce the work in css part, but I am not able to figure it how to add it on my webpack npm project.

I am having my index.html, script.js and style.css in "src" folder I don't want to change them. I need that in the index.html, I will able to use tailwind. that's it!!.

Here are some of the file's content attached for reference.

[webpack.dev.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69hNE.png)

[webpack.common.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik721.png)

[webpack.prod.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3aiq.png)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT5wB.png)

[all files directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6bsZ.png)

After installation When i start to run the project by "npm run dev" command it shows lots of error, I just want to know the correct steps by which I can able to install tailwind in my webpack npm project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see tailwind as an installed dependency in your package.json.
I recommed you install tailwind with PostCSS. The installation process is explained in detail on [tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss). Also make sure to include paths for all files in the content array in tailwind.config.js

Comment: I have installed tailwind CSS as mentioned on the website. But still the website loads as it loads before with no error, but No property of the tailwind is working on it, kindly can you help with that please.